# Is this sentence grammatically correct? (compare the social life in x neighborhoods with those in y neighborhoods)

Tags: relative-pronouns

I am working on my personal statement for grad school, and I am wondering whether this sentence is grammatically correct:

> I then conducted eight sets of observation to compare the social life and daily interactions in Hispanic neighborhoods with **those** in non-Hispanic neighborhoods.

I am concerned about the usage of "those" before "in non-Hispanic neighborhoods".

I think

> compare X in A with X in B

is the right structure, but in the sentence I used X is relatively long. Therefore, I think I may not want to restate X after the word "with", and instead I use the pronoun "those".

I am wondering whether it is OK to use "those" here to substitute "social life and daily interactions".

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Could you please comment on why you think **those** is or is not appropriate, otherwise you are asking for proofreading which is off topic on ELL and this question will probably be Closed.

Comment: OK. So I think "compare X in A with X in B" is the right structure, but since in the sentence I inputted, X is relatively long. Therefore, I think I may not want to restate X after the word "with", and I use a pron.- those. The question here is asking whether using the pron. to substitute X is proper here.

Comment: I find the phrase "eight sets of observation" hard to understand.  Do you mean you observed the same group pairs 8 different times, 8 different group pairs once each, or something else

Comment: I was trying to say eight different group pairs. Thank you for pointing out this place!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in using

> those

to substitute for

> the social life and daily interactions in Hispanic neighborhoods
>
> interactions in Hispanic neighborhoods and **those** non-Hispanic neighborhoods

in your sentence, also acceptable would be

> interactions in Hispanic neighborhoods **and** *(in)* non-Hispanic neighborhoods
>   interactions in Hispanic neighborhoods **to** those in non-Hispanic neighborhoods

Also, note that you should use

> eight sets of observation**s**